# Does the following cconjecture hold true for n objects with r outcomes and k objects being taken away?

Tags: probability

Does in always follow that for a group of n objects with r outcomes and k objects are taken away that:

${n \choose r} \to {n-k \choose r-k}$ different pairings of n-k objects with k so long as $k \lt r, r \gt 0, n \gt r$ which are to be taken away from the total set ${n \choose r}$

I know the answer to the first part. What I don't understand is the second part where the book says because of a total 2 choose 2 times 5 choose 1 which equals 5 out of the total 35 groups it follows there is 35-5=30 groups of men and three hundred total possible among the two sexes. Could someone explain the reasoning behind 2 choose 2 and 5 choose 1. I Mistakenly believed it would be sufficient to just subtract two from n and do 5 choose 3. Why is it that two is subtracted from r. I get that we would obviously have 5 objects but why 1 at a time?

Comment: You need to tell us what the original question was; as it stands, this is incomprehensible.

Comment: Okay I will probablly formulate a better question tomorrow and I hope to hear back from you. I will create a new question and be more specific and precise as to exactly what it is that I am asking

Answer (score 0):

To create a group of three from a pool of seven which includes a feuding pair:

There are $2\choose2$ ways to pick the feuding pair and $5\choose1$ ways to choose the third member of the committee from the remaining five men.

For a grand total of $${2\choose2}\times{5\choose1}$$